# python main window hangs with timer

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, gtk, pygtk

I need to turn on function from my main window and keep this function running because it checks some state ( it is again() function and I removed checking from this example ). This function must stay intact as it is now. But main window hangs. Please help.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pygtk
pygtk.require("2.0")
import gtk 
import gobject
import time
gtk.gdk.threads_init()

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.okno = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL) 
        self.okno.resize(400,150)
        self.okno.show_all()

        self.again()


    def again(self):
        i=0
        while 1:
            print i
            i=i+1           

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    gtk.threads_enter()
    gtk.main()
    gtk.threads_leave()
```

CHANGED:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pygtk
pygtk.require("2.0")
import gtk 
import gobject
import time
import threading, sys

gtk.gdk.threads_init()

class App(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        self.okno = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL) 
        self.okno.resize(400,150)
        self.okno.show_all()
        self.again()        

    def again(self):
        i=0
        while 1:
            print i
            sys.stdout.flush()
            i=i+1       
            time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    gtk.threads_enter()
    threading.Thread(target=App).start()
    gtk.threads_leave()
    gtk.main()
```

Comment: You aren't using threads correctly.  You should say `gtk.threads_enter()` just before `app = App()` and `gtk.threads_leave()` just after.  You aren't even using threads there, however, so you should also change `app = App()` to `threading.Thread(target=App).start()`.  You would need to import `threading`.

Comment: Zondo, thank you. I changed my code but it is not working as expected. Am  I missing something?

Comment: It's probably just that printing something with no pauses *and* dealing with window events is just too much to handle.

Comment: I added pause with time.sleep(10) but window is not responsive all time long

Comment: When printing and sleeping, you need to run `sys.stdout.flush()` after the `print` call.  I would suggest `while self.okno.get_visible():` instead of `while 1:` so that the printing doesn't go on forever even after the window is destroyed.  Also, when defining a window, you should usually put `self.okno.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)` there so that your program finishes when the window is closed.

Comment: I edited my code and added sys.stdout.flush() - it is the same

Comment: I just noticed that `App` inherits from `threading.Thread`.  You don't need that.  Instead of making `App` the target of a thread, start it with just `app = App()`, and make the `self.again()` call the target: `gtk.threads_enter()` `threading.Thread(target=self.again).start()` `gtk.threads_leave()`  Even better, initialize `self.i` to `0` in `__init__`, and in `again()`, just `print self.i; self.i += 1`.  Then, also in `__init__`, use `gobject.timeout_add_seconds(1, self.again)`

Comment: There is no need to both inherit from `Thread` and instantiate a `Thread` with an arbitrary target - you do one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot** use GTK API from different threads; only one thread is allowed to use GTK, and it's the thread that called `Gtk.main()` (and initialized the library, which is done automatically by the Python bindings when you import the Gtk module).

The correct way to use a thread with GTK is to create a worker thread to do a long-running job, and whenever the UI needs to be updated you should schedule a callback in the main loop, using `GLib.idle_add()`. The callable you pass to the `idle_add()` function is guaranteed to be called in the same thread as the one running the main loop.

You don't need to use the `threads_enter()` and `threads_leave()` API if you use a worker thread (and those functions are not portable anyway; they have been deprecated in GTK 3.0).